# Using lldb on mac os doesn't ask for Developer Tools Access

Tags: lldb

I'm following a tutorial on using lldb. I tried typing process attach -p  and I got error: attach failed: Error 1. However in the tutorial a screen pops up asking for "developer tools access needs to take control of another process for debugging to continue". I think this is why it won't work. Why does it not pop up?

Answer (score 1):

What were you trying to debug?  On Darwin systems, only processes that opt into being debugged can be, and most shipping apps (including all the system ones) do not opt into being debugged.

Since this isn't an issue with the general permission to debug, but rather the target proces rejecting your attach attempt, you wouldn't see the "Developer Tools" dialog box.  You machine is configured to debug, just not this process...

You can test this by building something yourself and then attaching to it.